# Can not upload Report to Power BI Report Server

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I've the **Power BI Desktop** RS Version as  1.5.7074.36177 (May 2019) and
Power BI Report Server (Development version): 2.73.5586.1501 64-bit (September, 2019)

I tried to save the report to PBI RS, it is throwing following error:

> We can't save this Power BI Desktop report because either it is newer version or has component parts that are not supported.

I was able to upload it previously and I'm not sure what settings have changed. It started giving the above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade your Power BI Report Server version to the latest available to make sure it’s compatible with users using the latest version of Power BI Desktop available.

1. Log in to the server that hosts your Power BI Report Server
2. Download the latest version of Power BI Report Server
3. Go to https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/report-server/
4. Click “Advanced download options”
5. Select your language and click “Download”
6. Check the box next to "PowerBIReportServer.exe and" "Next"
7. Run the downloaded .exe file and click “Upgrade Power BI Report Server”
8. Follow the prompts, and reboot the server when finished. This will cause a short amount of downtime.

You should now be able to access and save reports from/to the server as usual from all versions of Power BI Desktop.